# simple groovy program fails with error: No signature of method: java.lang.ProcessBuilder.inheritIO() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I'm scratching my head on this one, The program is as follows:

```
class MyClass {
    def static someMethod() {
        def pb = new ProcessBuilder("")
        pb.inheritIO()
        pb.setCommand(/* command list */)
        def process = pb.start()
        ...
        println "profit"
    }
}
```

except running the above (or the equivelant of) gives the output:

```
No signature of method: java.lang.ProcessBuilder.inheritIO() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

inheritIO is obviously a method [defined in the ProcessBuilder class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO%28%29)

so what is going wrong here?

**CONTEXT:** this is happening during a gradle build using jdk 7u55 except i imagine this info is unrelated. to me it looks like groovy has forgotten what it was doing.

**EDIT:** if i delete the pb.inheritIO() line then when i call pb.start() it throws another error:

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException
```

Comment: That's really odd. The error means that Groovy could locate the method (and you're actually using the right class) but it can't find one which takes no arguments - except that the method signature in the error message tells us that the method doesn't take any arguments... Can you try to run the code in a debugger?

Comment: what is a good way of inspecting the class's [ProcessBuilders] methods? given that debugging the script is not very straight forward (being a gradle script and all).

Comment: I would set a breakpoint at the place where the first exception is being thrown so you can look at the state of the various variables. That should give you an idea what is going on. Here is how you start Gradle in a debugger: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_do_you_attach_a_debugger_to_gradle_so_that_i_can_debug_it_running_a_task

Comment: Are you certain that it's definitely running on the JRE you think it is?  Try putting a `println System.getProperty('java.home')` at the top of that method.

Comment: Also the method to set the command list is `command(...)` not `setCommand(...)`

Comment: Ah ha! @IanRoberts you got me. Looks like I'm using the 1.6 jre. How would i change that? i.e. Override JAVA_HOME not edit it.

Comment: P.S. The code is located in my buildSrc directory (a gradle standard) and my `org.gradle.java.home` already equals `C:/Program Files/java/jdk1.7.0_55`. in the rootProject build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer is quite involved but very specific to my setup:

although i have my org.gradle.java.home property set to the java 1.7 jdk, I am using a properties plugin that uses different property files according to an environment variable called `environmentName` this property was set to the incorrect value thus it was reading JAVA_HOME from my environment rather than the variable i set in the property file i wanted. I changed this and the jre was switched to the correct runtime.